# Skyrim: Curse of the crappy potions after resto looping

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I did the Restoration Loop exploit to get an item that increases my carry weight by like 2147455654646 points, and ever since I did that and took off my Fortify Alchemy gear, all of my potions are really, really bad. Before I did this, I could make Invisibility potions that lasted for 39 seconds, and now I can only make ones that last for 4 seconds. I'm on the PS3, but I could easily convert my save to PC format, and use console commands. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try putting your fortify alchemy gear back on?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work. I even tried making new Alchemy gear, and it didn't work. In fact, I think it made it worse. Without any gear, potions last for 4 seconds, and with gear, potions last for 3 seconds.

Comment: I tried making the skill Legendary to level it down back to 15 and releveling it, but that didn't help.

Comment: I think you caused overflow on a variable somewhere (A typical game bug, you know, having 6+billion cash suddenly turns into -6 billion). Have you looked at the alchemy wiki pages? You cannot be the first one to encounter this.

Comment: I checked the wiki pages (UESP), but they didn't say anything helpful. I think I got an overflow on my Carry Weight with that amulet I made, but unequipping it does not help. Also, a side effect of using said amulet is that my max Carry Weight was decreased all the way back to 300 points when not wearing the amulet, like at level 1. If I equip my super OP alchemy items I made with a super OP enchanting potion, then I can make good potions, but they're (obviously) OP, and I just want to make normal potions.

Comment: Can confirm that Alchemy gear makes potion making worse. Without Alchemy gear I can make Frenzy potions that affect things up to level 1, and with gear, it says up to level 0.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out drink restoration potions till it has a minus followed by a large number and it will reset the ridiculous number